# ¿Cómo cambiar el atributo de texto de un TextView desde Activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

Estoy usando Android Studio y quiero que el texto que se muestre en un `TextView` provenga del archivo `Strings.xml`

Por ejemplo estos dos textos:

```
<string name="1">texto1</string>

<string name="2"texto2</string>
```

Y que el `TextView` primero muestre **"Texto 1"** y al pulsar un botón cambie y muestre **"Texto 2"**.

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo, tan solo debes de agregar la referencia al string en vez de una secuencia char.

Ejemplos:
String.xml:

```
<string name="texto1">texto1</string>
 <string name="texto2"texto2</string>
```

En tu actividad preferiblemente dentro de onCreate():

```
TextView txtTexto = findViewById(R.Id.textView1);

txtTexto.setText(R.String.texto1);
```

Y al presionar el botón ejecutas este codigo:

```
txtTexto.setText(R.String.texto2);
```